# ubuntu 9.10 screen flickering problem on Thinkpad R31 with Intel 83830 Graphics

Tags: ubuntu, thinkpad

I am trying to revitalize an old Thinkpad R31 that has the Intel 82830 graphics and only 256 MB of RAM.

I have tried a Xubuntu 9.10 Live CD. After booting the screen blinks so much that it is practically unreadable.

I have searched for updated IBM Thinkpad drivers but I only found drivers for Windows on the Thinkpad support web site.

**EDIT:** I have changed the title and the description. It is not a problem of the drivers. It seems to be a problem with the kernel. See my own answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have  collected more information, and I solved my problem.

Here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1318523 is an exact description of the very same problem

And here http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1307879.html is an explanation of a possible answer

essentially the problem is a conflict of the intel 830 driver and Kernel probing, which is enabled by default since Kernel 2.6.30-10.12 ( see this link https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/KernelModeSetting )

So, the solution to the screen problem is **disabling Kernel probing** by setting the option `i915.modeset=0` in the kernel boot command line.

But, this leads to another different problem.

As documented in some web sites, this fix is accomplished by adding the option in `/boot/grub/menu.lst`

But, there is no `/boot/grub/menu.lst` in my xubuntu 9.10 .

Looking further, I found `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` instead.

`grub.cfg` has a big warning in its header DO NOT EDIT THIS.

The grub.cfg header documents that the grub.cfg file is generated from `/etc/default/grub`.

So following this path, I came up with **the solution**

---

1. I modified `/etc/default/grub` adding `i915.modeset=0` to the default linux boot `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`
2. Then I regenerated `grub.cfg` with `update-grub`

---

And .. **it works**.

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly to eliminate the flashing external display problem on my ThinkPad R31 running Xubuntu 12.04.2

When changed, the actual line in grub was (note the quotes):

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.modeset=0"

Thanks!